# Retrieve Statistics from ActiveMQ with Stompy

Tags: python, python-3.x, activemq-classic, stomp

Really simple question, is the a way to access the statistic of an ActiveMQ broker using the Stompy module or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the [Broker Statistics Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) and then use your Stomp client to process the messages it returns.  ActiveMQ allows you to add [transformations](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html#Stomp-Messagetransformations) to Stomp subscriptions so you can get the resulting message in XML or JSON.  There's other articles out there you can read on this topic, Google search is your friend.